# Laravel 4 application structure: how to organize User and his Profile models using SOLID principles

Tags: php, laravel

Read many books about Laravel 4 and it's strucutre using interfaces and implementations throught IoC container.
So now of all that information I don't understand anything.

At example i have such structure:

```
app
-- config
-- database
-- lang
-- ...
-- logic
-- -- MyAPP
-- -- -- Controllers
-- -- -- Interfaces
-- -- -- Libraries

-- -- -- Models
-- -- -- -- User
-- -- -- -- -- Profile.php
-- -- -- -- -- User.php

-- -- -- Repositories
-- -- -- ServiceProviders
```

I have User model and Profile model which can't exist without User model, because it has one to one relationship.

At example i have UserInterface:

```
interface UserInterface
{
    public function find($userId);

    public function findProfile($userId);

    public function replace($userId, $attributes, $profileAttributes);
}
```

And implementation which looks like this:

```
class UserRepository implements UserInterface
{
    protected $user;

    protected $profile;

    public function __construct(Model $user, Model $profile)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        $this->profile = $profile;
    }

    public function find($userId)
    {
        return $this->user->find($userId);
    }

    public function findProfile($userId)
    {
        return $this->profile->where('user_id', $userId)->first();
    }   

    public function replace($userId, $attributes, $profileAttributes)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

So my question is, that is it good practice if I try to implement SOLID principles that UserRepository injects two models User and Profile, or it would be right way to create ProfileInterface and inject it into UserRepository so there would be something like this:

```
public function __construct(Model $user, ProfileInterface $profile)
```

Thing that I cant understand, is what would be right way to organize dependencies. Because i think that ProfileInterface should have all Profile functionality, but on other side it cant exist without User, because we fisrty create user in table and then add in second user_profiles table it's details.

Where would be better to store functionality. user and his UserProfile functionality in one Interface - UserInterface or in to separate interfaces: UserInterface and ProfileInterface which is injected in UserInterface ?

And if ProfileInterface is injected into UserInterface how i should create new user ( using Eloquent )?

Comment: Are you ever going to load a User without loading their Profile?

Comment: No, i will always access $user, and will access his profile throught relationship like this; $user->profile->some_profile_field, where profile is relationship method that points to Profile model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, I don't see a need for a `ProfileRepository` since it's inherently linked with the `User` model.  And if you are always returning a `User` with their `Profile` then I would do a few things -

1. Make sure the `User` model has a relationship with the `Profile` model.  Such as `belongsTo`.  See: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships
2. In the repository, eager load the `Profile` with the `User`.  See: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading

I also wouldn't necessarily pass the `User` model in at the constructor.  It's probably better to pass it to only the methods that need it.

```
public function find($id)
{
  // returns User with Profile, if you have relationships set up
  return User::with('profile')->find($id);
}

public function save(User $user)
{
  // do some save logic here, like:
  $user->save();
}
```

... and so on.

Comment: I think that if you will use User:: in statical way, you will brake one of the SOLID principles, so Repository will be less testable. But i agree with answer that only User model can be used. Only i have another question then. How saving of new user will be performed ? Can something like that be done: $user = $this->user->create($attributes); $user->profile->somefield = 'somevalue'; ? $user->profile->save() ???

Comment: Using the model statically like that is how Eloquent is designed; if you're not doing that method, you're not using Eloquent and will need to design a bit further.

Comment: One of the books, that i have read was "Implementing Laravel by Chris Fidao". Book is about l4 structure using interfaces. Here is Repo example: https://github.com/fideloper/Implementing-Laravel/blob/master/app/Impl/Repo/Status/EloquentStatus.php He isn't using Eloquent staticaly nowhere in his code. What logic is right one ? Your or his ?

Comment: Not sure - hop over to #laravel on IRC and discuss!

Comment: `User::...` in l4 is just a syntactical sugar that is called Facade. Behind the scenes it is pulled out of the IoC container where you can replace the implementation.http://laravel.com/docs/facades